# Replace all row names in R with substring of these names

Tags: r

For instance, I have : AO-A12D.01TCGA 
I want the row name to consist only of "A12D"

I also have another kind of row name,  but this time the order is different:
TCGA-A2-A0T2
I want it to be replaced by A0T2 . Here the 4 characters are found in the end while in the first case they are in the middle.

How can I do it?

Edit : in the first case the separator is based on the . and - as the 4 characters are between them always
In the second case the 4 characters are just the last 4 characters, no separators

Comment: please `dput()` your sample data. Please also explain the logic behind the example. Is it just based on the position of the `-` and `.`?

Comment: What defines the string you want as distinct from the rest of the rowname? Is it always 4 characters long? Might there be other substrings that are also 4 characters long in a given rowname? Are `-` and `.` the only separators?

Comment: in the first case it is based on the - and .      while in the second case I just need to take the last 4 characters

Comment: In your second case, there are 2 strings 4 characters long, so how should we decide to use "A0T2" instead of "TCGA"?

Comment: I said in my question that in the second case we just need the last 4 characters

Comment: Not sure why this gets so many down votes. If those are the only two cases, they are all you need for a reproducible example. It's also pretty clear to me what OP wants to match from those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Need a reproducible example.

Probably you're looking for something like:

```
#string AO-A12D.01TCGA --> A12D
row.names(x)<-gsub(".*-(.*)[.].*", "\\1", row.names(x)) #where x has values     like "AO-A12D.01TCGA"

#string TCGA-A2-A0T2 --> TCGA-A2-A0T2
row.names(x)<-gsub(".*-.*-(.*)", "\\1", row.names(x)) #where x has values like "TCGA-A2-A0T2"

#row.names gets row names of data frame
#gsub defines a regular expression/pattern, where:
#gsub("pattern", "stuff to replace pattern with", data)
#in regular expression language:  
#.* = anything
#[.] = a literal "dot" 
#(string) = part of pattern you want to keep
#\\1 means keep only the stuff in parentheses
```

By the way, based on my tests, neither of these regular expressions will produce erroneous errors by subsetting the wrong string type if you call them on the same data set.

Comment: sorry but I also have a pattern same as AO.A12D.01TCGA I also want to extract A12D , what should I change? It's delimited by two . I'm really not good at regular expressions... Your code works perfectly on the cases i mentioned in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd tackle it, but until you give a reproducible sample, we really can't do much more than speculate:

Take the `rownames` as they are, split by the characters `-` and `.`, then remove the first substring (pure speculation that you'll never need the first part of the string), then take only the remaining strings with character length 4:

```
library( magrittr )
new.rownames <- rownames( x ) %>%
  strsplit( "-|[.]" ) %>%
  lapply( function(x) x[ -1 ] ) %>%
  sapply( function(x) x[ nchar( x ) == 4 ] )
```

This returns (for the 3 examples you've given):

```
> new.rownames
[1] "A12D" "A0T2" "A12D"
```

Then apply those new names to the original data.

```
rownames(x) <- new.rownames
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are the *only* two formats, you can use *positive lookbehind* and `regmatches` to get what you want:

```
rownames = c("AO-A12D.01TCGA", "TCGA-A2-A0T2")
unlist(regmatches(rownames, gregexpr("(?<=-)[[:alnum:]]{4}", rownames, perl = TRUE)))

[1] "A12D" "A0T2"
```

`(?<=-)` is the positive lookbehind part where you want `gregexpr` to only give you the positions of 4 alphanumerics that is right after a `-` sign. `regmatches` takes `gregexpr` as input and returns a list of *matches* only. Note that you need `perl = TRUE` since lookbehinds and lookaheads only work with perl.

Since in your comment under @griffmer's answer you mentioned a third case, I will demonstrate how to do this just by modifying my regex a little:

```
rownames = c("AO-A12D.01TCGA", "TCGA-A2-A0T2", "AO.A12D.01TCGA")
unlist(regmatches(rownames, gregexpr("(?<=[-.])[[:alnum:]]{4}\\b", rownames, perl = TRUE)))

[1] "A12D" "A0T2" "A12D"
```

Here, your 4 character code can either be followed by a `-` or a `.`. So just add the dot in the lookbehind `(?<=[-.])`. With this third case however, "01TC" in `rownames[1]` and in `rownames[3]` will also match, which is not what we want. By adding `\\b` which stands for *word boundary*, "01TC" in both cases will not be matched because it is followed by a "G", while "A12D", "A0T2", and "A12D" will.